# Is HIbernate Search worth for database Search?

Tags: search, spring-mvc, hibernate-search

My application is basically a people directory -lookup(about 1500 people) with all the information contained in database? I started to build this using SPRING-Hibernate and I arrived at the point to implement people search.. To be honest I have never done this kind of thing and completely clueless about where to start. I want to know if it is worth to learn and implement HibernateSearch for my application as it doesn't have any document search needs and just database search where tables have joins/associations?

Also if there are any tutorials available on internet which can guide me on starting this kind of project please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use hibernate-search, because it has many functionalies and utilities...
Hibernate-search contains full-text search and it uses Apache Lucene core for creating indexes etc.

1. [Apache Lucene docs](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html)
2. [Hibernate Search Documentation & Examples, Reference Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/)